# Opening Chrome From Command Line

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, command-prompt

I have the following batch file:

```
@echo off
REM Starts a chrome browser with multiple tabbed sites
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe "site1.com" "site2.com"
```

But when I run it, it causes the prompt to hang and renders it unusable until Chrome is closed. (Or, if I am not using the prompt and run it from the icon, it opens a blank prompt that is unusable and disappears when Chrome is closed.)

Is there any way to prevent this? I.E. once the webpages are open, the prompt is no longer tied up.

It opens the webpages just fine. I've also noticed that if there's already a chrome window open, the batch runs fine (leaving a usable prompt), adding the tabs to the existing chrome session.

Comment: This will work: `google-chrome google.com`

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Have a look into the `start` command. It should do what you're trying to achieve.

Also, you might be able to leave out path to chrome. The following works on Windows 7:

`start chrome "site1.com" "site2.com"`

Comment: how can you provide parameters like: google-chrome --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist

Comment: Include any extra arguments before the URLs. start chrome --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist "site1.com" "site2.com"

Comment: how to open with a user profile? I have multiple chrome user profiles. @GavinH

Comment: how can i start chrome with ubuntu?

Answer (score 9):

Use the start command as follows.

`start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.google.com`

It will be better to close chrome instances before you open a new one. You can do that as follows:

```
taskkill /IM chrome.exe
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.google.com
```

That'll work for you.

Comment: @Vidz use `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.google.com`

Comment: @Vidz Thanks. I have the same problem. But my dafault browser is IE (internet explorer).

Comment: how would you specify a port number?

Comment: @NilsSens - you can specify the port number like

`start chrome "http:localhost:88\bar"`

Where `88` is the port number.  The colon is needed between the domain and the port.

Answer (score 8):

`C:\>start chrome "http://site1.com"` works on Windows Vista.

Comment: What does that add to the accepted answer, given one year earlier?

Answer (score 8):

Let's take a look at the `start` command.

Open Windows command prompt

To open a new Chrome window (blank), type the following:

```
start chrome --new-window
```

or

```
start chrome
```

To open a URL in Chrome, type the following:

```
start chrome --new-window "http://www.iot.qa/2018/02/narrowband-iot.html"
```

To open a URL in Chrome in incognito mode, type the following:

```
start chrome --new-window --incognito "http://www.iot.qa/2018/02/narrowband-iot.html"
```

or

```
start chrome --incognito "http://www.iot.qa/2018/02/narrowband-iot.html"
```

Answer (score 5):

you can create batch file and insert into it the bellow line:

```
cmd /k start chrome "http://yourWebSite.com
```

after that you do just double click on this batch file.

Answer (score 3):

open command prompt and type

```
cd\ (enter)
```

then type

```
start chrome "www.google.com"(any website you require)
```

Answer (score 2):

> start chrome

Just Type ***start chrome*** in your windows terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this for `Ubuntu` users for reference.

Run command `google-chrome "http://localhost/"`

Replace your desired URL in the parameter.

You can get more options like incognito mode etc.
Run `google-chrome --help` to see the options.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open incognito window, put the command below:

start chrome /incognito

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows:type on Command Prompt and hit enter. 
start chrome (chrome)
start firefox (firefox) 
Ubuntu:type on terminal and hit enter.
google-chrome (chrome)
firefox (firefox) 

if you want to open with path you have to added relative path with command(google-chrome www.facebook.com)
```