# Open chrome in windows from the command line in a new window

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cmd

I tried this command from the cmd prompt:

```
start "c:\program files (x86)\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe" --new-window "http://localhost:8080:/debug?port=5858"
```

and I get "windows can not find '--new-window'

If I remove the start command, it works fine.  If I leave the start command but remove the --new-window parm then the url is opened in my default browser (ie).

I've tried several variations of the above but can't get it to work.

What is the correct syntax for the start command to open chrome with the given url in a new window?

Comment: For anyone coming here for an answer, I suggest taking a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348840/opening-chrome-from-command-line) question too.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Answer is there : [Using the "start" command with parameters passed to the started program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-dos-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program)

```
start "" "c:\program files (x86)\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe" --new-window "http://localhost:8080:/debug?port=5858"
```

(add empty title parameter at the beginning of the line)

Comment: Is there a way we can execute this code from c# program? I tried ProcessStartInfo class but that didn't worked out

Answer (score 11):

In Windows 10, following command works:

```
start chrome --new-window "https://www.facebook.com"
```

This works perfectly in cmd.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put this in a batchfile, then you can play with size and position to:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window "http://brianp.dk/" --window-size="2560,1000" --window-position="0,0" --user-data-dir="D:/Test/Profiles/1"
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window "http://borsen.dk/" --start-maximized --window-position="2560,000" --user-data-dir="D:/Test/Profiles/2"
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window "http://penge.dk/" --window-size="1280,1000" --window-position="0000,1000" --user-data-dir="D:/Test/Profiles/3"
```