# Javascript reading local/(same machine as the html) xml file

Tags: javascript, xml

My goal is to read in a file test.xml which is in the same folder as my index.html.

I know that I can pull in script files with something like `<script src="index.js></script>`, but is there a way for me to do the same with an xml file `<xml src="test.xml"><xml>`.

I do not want to use the AJAX XMLHttpRequest because the index.html may not be hosted on an http server, but instead opened like a normal file in chrome.

Do I have any options when it comes to opening up this xml file, or will it have to be hosted on a http server? I guess another option would be to store the whole xml file inside of a javascript variable, but this seems unnecessary.

Comment: worst case, `<script type="text/xml" src="test.xml"></script>`, then use DOM .innerHTML to extract the raw .xml

Answer (score 0):

> do not want to use the AJAX XMLHttpRequest because the index.html may
>   not be hosted on an http server, but instead opened like a normal file
>   in chrome.

Try launching chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag set . Should then be able to use `XMLHttpRequest` to retrieve file in local filesystem

*nix

`/usr/bin/google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`

*indows

```
start chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

See [How do I make the Google Chrome flag “--allow-file-access-from-files” permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent/192996) , [Opening Chrome From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348840/opening-chrome-from-command-line)

Comment: This is still pretty sub-ideal for what I am trying to do. I mentioned chrome in my example, but to me it is unknown what browser will be used to access this html file. Also, I don't want to force someone to enable a flag in order to use the html file.

Comment: _"This is still pretty sub-ideal for what I am trying to do. I mentioned chrome in my example, but to me it is unknown what browser will be used to access this html file. Also, I don't want to force someone to enable a flag in order to use the html file."_ ? Not exactly certain what "trying to do" consists of ? If requirement is _"read in a file test.xml which is in the same folder as **my** index.html"_ , would not "force someone"  else to enable a flag , as would be local file at _your_ local filesystem ?

Comment: Can include more details describing requirment at Question ?