# How to open google chrome from terminal?

Tags: git, bash, google-chrome, terminal, alias

I'm trying to create an alias that opens google chrome to localhost. Port 80 in this case.

I'd also really like to be able to be in any git directory and have it open that specific project in the browser, but I'm not sure if that's even possible.

- How do I open google chrome from the terminal?
- What alias could I use to open the current git project in the browser?

More Details:

1. My localhost is set to port 80.
2. I store my git repositories in ~/Sites/ - meaning if I wanted to view any project in the browser it would be found here: `http://localhost/FILENAME`

Thank You

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/234663/what-command-should-i-type-to-run-chrome-from-the-terminal

Comment: If you are using Git Bash, then this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348840/opening-chrome-from-command-line

You would run: `start chrome "http://localhost"`

Comment: @glennjackman - OS X El Capitan 10.11.2

Comment: If chrome is your default browser, `open http://localhost` will do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UPDATE:

1. How do I open google chrome from the terminal?

Thank you for the quick response. `open http://localhost/` opened that domain in my default browser on my Mac.

2. What alias could I use to open the current git project in the browser?

I ended up writing this alias, did the trick:

```
# Opens git file's localhost; ${PWD##*/} is the current directory's name
alias lcl='open "http://localhost/${PWD##*/}/"'
```

Thank you again!

Comment: If someone else wants to use it inside a Makefile on linux, it worked for me when I used `xdg-open`. Found the tip here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35811643/1594227

Answer (score 147):

From the macOS Terminal, use `open` with the `-a` flag and give the name of the app you want to open. In this case "Google Chrome". You may pass it a file or URL you want it to open with.

```
open -a "Google Chrome" index.html
```

Comment: I just added `alias chrome="open -a 'Google Chrome'"` to my `.zshrc` file. Thank you!

Comment: how do you pass flags

Comment: @MuhammadUmer To pass flags e.g. `--disable-web-security`, use `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-web-security`

Comment: If Chrome is your default browser, just `open index.html` works as well.

Answer (score 47):

On Linux, just use this command in a terminal:

```
google-chrome
```

Comment: Worth noting that, unlike `xdg-open` (or `open` on macOS) for using the default browser, `google-chrome` runs _synchronously_, i.e., blocks the calling shell until the newly opened tab is closed; appending `&` makes it asynchronous.

Comment: In what scenario did it run in sync? I wasn't able to reproduce the sync behaviour you talked about, @mklement0 , always works async to me, never waits for tab to close.

Comment: @ÍhorMé: Google Chrome 76.0.3809.87 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: I'm also on that. Actually, now I find I do get this exp with `google-chrome http://example --no-sandbox`. And when I run without --no-sandbox I don't, but I can't run without that one under root. Throws 
`[32610:32610:0815/130649.955364:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.`

Answer (score 32):

If you just want to open the Google Chrome from terminal instantly for once then 
`open -a "Google Chrome"` 
works fine from Mac Terminal.

If you want to use an alias to call Chrome from terminal then you need to edit the bash profile and add an alias on `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` file.The steps are below :

- Edit `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` file and add the following line `alias chrome="open -a 'Google Chrome'"`
- Save and close the file.
- Logout and relaunch Terminal
- Type `chrome filename` for opening a local file.
- Type `chrome url` for opening url.

Comment: bash has a `~/.bashrc` as well. I would not recommend aliases in `~/.profile`, that is more about env variable.

Comment: What is the -a ? I can't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 6):

just type

```
google-chrome
```

it works. Thanks.

Comment: does not work in macOS Catalina. However just using open <URL> works if chrome is your default browser.

Comment: actually, i do work in ubuntu, and its working fine. But am not sure in macOS.

Comment: Doesn't work on macOS Sonoma either

Answer (score 6):

For **macOS** you can use this command:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome "https://google.com"
```

Answer (score 4):

on mac terminal (at least in ZSH): `open stackoverflow.com` (opens site in new tab in your chrome default browser)

Answer (score 4):

Use command

```
google-chrome-stable
```

We can also use command

```
google-chrome
```

To open terminal but in my case when I make an interrupt `ctrl + c` then it get closed so I would recommend to use `google-chrome-stable` instead of `google-chrome`

Answer (score 4):

For **Windows**:

```
start chrome "https://www.google.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Terminal**, type `open -a Google\ Chrome`

This will open Google Chrome application without any need to manipulate directories!

Answer (score 2):

**On linux [ubuntu] in terminal, write:**

```
google-chrome 'https://google.com' 2> /dev/null
```

ending part `2> /dev/null` ommits output from command in terminal and allows to type without disturbing comments from that command.

**for new-ones in scripting (linux users):**

u can also create some nice readable function in `~/.bashrc` directory like:

```
open(){
    google-chrome $1 2> /dev/null
}
```

and in terminal using it like this:

```
open htts://google.com
```