# Git Bash bash: open: command not found

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

I'm new to Git Bash, just freshly downloaded this for use in my class today, on the first class module it ask me to *cd* in to different directory and *ls* the content which works perfectly fine in Git Bash, then it ask me to open a README.md file in a folder with the command:

open README.md

then this error message show up:

bash: open: command not found

I know I *cd* in to the correct folder, and *ls* does shows the the README.md file, this is a freshly installed and most updated Git Bash, can't imagine there would be a missing link or altered in this program... what can I do? please help thank you!

I'm using Windows 8 with Git for windows

Comment: "open" is native on OS X, on linux you can just define it as alias open=xdg-open, on windows I think the equivalent is "start".   Hunt up how to associate file types with programs.

Comment: Great! thank you! at lease I know it is not my Git Bash problem, thank you!

Comment: You may follow this link. here has the verified answere.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253376/open-command-to-open-a-file-in-an-application

Answer (score 111):

> bash: open: command not found

This error message is trying to tell you that there is no such command called "open". There's nothing wrong with the `README.md`.

- OSX - `open` is a universal opener in OSX
- Linux - has `xdg-open`
- Windows - use `start`

But you don't need to take the instructions literally. It's not really important how you open the readme file. You can open it with the `less` command to view the content inside the terminal, or you can open it with `notepad` for editing in a text editor.

Comment: Great! so I wont worry about it then! at lease I know it is not my system problem, Thank you! I'm thinking if I should get a Mac...

Comment: Windows has start. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-equivalent-of-xdg-open-on-Windows

Answer (score 7):

**`open` is a linux specific command for Git Bash**

You can access your file using the `start` command like
`start filename.extension` this will open your file using *Notepad* if you are using *Windows 10*.

To access file with some text editor you can simply write the command as `start texteditorname filename.extension`.

To access file with **VS Code just** simply type `start code filename.extension`.

To access file with **ATOM** just simply type `start atom filename.extension`.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem at first when I started using Git Bash in my *Windows computer*.
I wanted to open a folder on my Desktop.
I specified the current directory, which was `cd Desktop/test` and then I gave the command `open .` to open the 'test' file, and I received `bash: open: command not found`.
I searched through the internet to find a way to open the file, and then finally I tried this one and it worked.

Solution :

1. Specify the root directory of the file -> `cd Desktop`
2. use "start" keyword and give the file name that you want to open -> `start test`

Answer (score 2):

As described in the first Answer, I used "start" to open my Text File and it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because file opening varies in command line from os to os

so if you are in

1. mac os - try open  in terminal
2. Linux - has xdg-open
3. Windows - use start  in terminal

this will probably fix your problem,  if not then try to open that .gitignore file in vscode

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu and instead of using open or start, use explorer.exe if you're trying to open in the browser.

`explorer.exe filename`

for example:

`explorer.exe index.html`

Answer (score 0):

You could also just try it without "start". In my case, "subl ." and "code ." both work to open the cwd in the respective editors. I assume it is just an alias for "subl start"/"code start".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).