# How can I create an automatic script to run server for Django project

Tags: python, django, batch-file, executable

I am working on a project using Django, every time i wanna run the script, i enter the command line:

```
>python manage.py runserver
```

How can I create an exec file that will run this command and open the 127.8.0.0 address in my browser when i just click on it ?

Comment: Why an exe? If you are using windows create a .bat file that does that. If you are using a Mac or Linux create a shell script that runs it. There's no need to have to compile it. You could run the first command, putting it into the background, then run the second to launch a browser. If you are using chrome see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796888/how-to-open-google-chrome-from-terminal

Answer (score 3):

Just create a `.bat` file. Example like this:

```
start cmd /k "cd E:\OE_Monitoring && oenv\Scripts\activate.bat && cd src\oe_project && python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000"
```

**General syntax**

```
start cmd /k "cd YourPathFolder && YourVirtualEnvironment\Scripts\activate.bat && cd YourPath\FolderContainManagePy && python manage.py runserver your_address:your_port"
```

Or you can add `default address` and `default port` in your `settings.py`:

```
from django.core.management.commands.runserver import Command as runserver

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
runserver.default_port = '8000'
runserver.default_addr = '127.0.0.1'
```

And file script just need run `python manage.py runserver` instead of `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`

**Another case**: If location of script at drive `D` and you want run project at drive `E`, we need change drive first (example `E: && cd your_path...`), but I recommend put script into project folder.

```
start cmd /k "YourDrive: && cd YourFolder && YourVirtualEnvironment\Scripts\activate.bat && cd YourPath\FolderContainManagePy && python manage.py runserver your_address:your_port"
```

Comment: but this wouldn't work on a computer that doesn't have python and the necessary packages installed. I want to create an automatic script that would run when you double click on it even when it's another user on his own computer.