# ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

I'm trying to open google chrome from terminal in Ubuntu but after submiting `google-chrome` I'm getting this error:
`ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported`

I've installed it by following this tutorial: https://itsfoss.com/install-chrome-ubuntu/

I've looked at this but it didn't help me [How to open google chrome from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796888/how-to-open-google-chrome-from-terminal)

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: I've had the same issue in GitHub Actions working with playwright. I'd love to see a solution. https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/1277

Answer (score 2):

I just ran
`sudo apt list --upgradable`
Chrome was one of the upgradable list, then ran the command
`sudo apt upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, updating the GPU drivers resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Chromium via Snap instead (`sudo snap install chromium`).  I get the same error message, but the browser appears to be running correctly anyway.  I'd still like to know what it means and how to fix it....