# Script to close browser tabs

Tags: javascript, batch-file, vbscript

I am currently in school and wanted to make a batch file that opens all links as follows:

```
@echo off
start chrome
start https:URL1
start https:URL2
start https:URL3
```

Now it opens a new chrome window. The problem is that it also opens an empty first tab. I tried to figure out key inputs like "^{TAB}" and "^w" in VBS but sadly couldn't. Is there a way to close the first tab with VBS or javascript from a batch-file? All help is appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `start chrome` line?

Comment: It opens the pages in the current chrome window. My goal is to have them in a new window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening Chrome From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348840/opening-chrome-from-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

Updated code.

```
@echo off
start chrome --new-window "www.cnn.com" "www.espn.com" "www.microsoft.com"
```

Comment: Thanks but this only works half of the time with lower T-values. Is there a way the next line will run when the previous is finished without pre-set timout?

Comment: Don't you think I would have provided that answer up front?