# PySimpleGUI window crashes after opening Chrome, but only if Chrome isn't already open

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui, windows-11, os.system

I'm pretty new to Python and have been working with PySimpleGUI. I have created a simple program in Windows 11 that opens Google when you press a button on the GUI. It works fine if Chrome is already open, but it crashes after pressing the "Go" button if Chrome isn't already open. I'm using Python 3.11.4 and PySimpleGUI 4.60.5.

Here is the code that I have:

```python
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os


layout = [
    [sg.Text('Press "Open Google" to open Google.')],
    [sg.Button("Exit"), sg.Button("Open Google", key = "-GOOGLE-")]
]
window = sg.Window("Test Window", layout)

b=0
while True:
    b+=1
    event, values = window.Read()

    if event in ("Exit", sg.WIN_CLOSED):
        window.Close()
        break
    if event == "-GOOGLE-":
        os.system("\"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\" -incognito https://google.com")
```

I don't want to use Chrome web driver, I'm trying to open a normal Chrome window.

Comment: Maybe use `webbrowser.open_new_tab(URL_OF_YOUR_CHOICE)`?

Comment: That does work, but that doesn't allow for it to be opened in incognito mode. Is there any way you know to be able to open incognito?

Comment: Don't use os.system?  Launch using a subprocess in a different way.  Many approaches are likely available so experiment.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it crashes"? Is there an error code, message, or traceback? Which Chrome CLI documentation did you reference to come up with this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is laid out a lot better here:
[Opening Chrome From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348840/opening-chrome-from-command-line).

The problem was with the command itself. For some reason, opening chrome.exe without a chrome tab open causes the prompt to hang, and not be able to fully execute. Using `start chrome -incognito "site1.com"` works fine. In python, this would look like:

```python
os.system("start chrome -incognito https://google.com")
```

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the recommendation to use `webbrowser`....

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import webbrowser


layout = [[sg.Text('Press "Open Google" to open Google.')], [sg.Button("Exit"), sg.Button("Open Google", key = "-GOOGLE-")] ]

window = sg.Window("Test Window", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in ("Exit", sg.WIN_CLOSED):
        window.close()
        break
    if event == "-GOOGLE-":
        webbrowser.get('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --incognito').open_new('https://www.google.com')
```